# Jquery ajax call with prompt not working

Tags: jquery, prompt

I'm putting a "Lost password" link in my login form.

The link in the form is in a div with id **pwdforget**

I do not want to submit the form, just prompting for an email address, looking into the db to verify whether such address exists, sending an email or returning an error in case email doesn't exist

My jquery script is quite basic (I use **impromptu** for the prompt, but I have the same problem with any other routine, even with the basic javascript prompt)

```
$('#pwdforget').click(function() {
  $.Prompt("Insert your email address","", "", function(r) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'pwdforget.php?email='+r,
      success: function(res){
        result = $.trim(res);
        if(result=="ok") {
          alert("Thank you");
        } else {
          alert("Bad address");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Looking into the console, I can verify that the address is sent to the php file, but I get no answer from the file, nor any action takes place. I created an empty php file, which just echoes "ok", but in the **success** part of the ajax call I noticed that the **res** variable is always empty, no matter what is echoed from the php file.

I also noticed that nothing happens in the php file (I tried putting some variable with firephp, and the console echoes noting)

I use $.ajax every day, but this is the first time I use it with javascript prompt.

Any clue?
Thanks
Alfa

Answer (score 3):

You can try .done().

```
$.ajax({}).done(function ( data ) { alert(data); })
```

This is working.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var  r=prompt("enter your email");
  if(r){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'pwdforget.php?email='+r,
      success: function(res){
      $('body').html(res);
      }
  });} });
</script>
```

Comment: The code i updated is working first be sure that your php file is returning something